# Assemly language, code correction, and if statements

Tags: assembly, if-statement, x86, comparison

Considering the numbers signed (as in `+`, `-`), write a code extract that checks if:

`[EAX]*[ESI + 4*EBX]%[EDX + 3] |ECX%[EDX + 3]` is less or equal to `[EBX + 20]`, and if true, put `1` in `EAX`.

This is what I have so far, but I cant figure out how to actually compare it to `[EBX + 20]`:

```
 MOVSX EAX, [input1]
 MOVSX ESI, [input2]
 MOVSX EBX, [input3]
 MOVSX EDX, [input4]
 IMUL EBX, 4
 ADD ESI,EBX
 IMUL EAX, ESI
 ADD EDX, 3
 IDIV ECX, EDX
 OR EDX, ECX
 IDIV EAX, EDX
```

This code is missing the comparison to `EBX + 20`, and putting `1` into `EAX`. Can I also interpret `%` as `IDIV`?

By answering this you help my whole systems programming class (elective). Thank in advance!

Comment: Most(all that I can think of) assembly languages support a CMP instruction, search your reference for that. Some have more refined instructions like JLE(jump less than) which could be useful in this case.

Comment: But is my piece of code actually good? I'm not sure... I mean is it doing what it should be doing?

Comment: The person most suited to determining whether your code works is *you*.

Comment: What is the size of input variables (input1..4)?

Comment: The assignment doesn't tell me anything, assume whatever fits :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice, that IDIV can't divide ecx by anything. It works only on EAX:EDX pair. This way, you need to not use EDX for anything else.

The **square brackets** in assembly language means **the memory pointed by the address in the brackets**. In the terms of the task, only ecx is used by its value. All other registers contain some memory addresses and the values have to be read from the memory.

Also I assume all registers have the proper values on the input:

```
compare:
         mov    eax, [eax]         ; eax = [eax]
         imul   eax, [esi+4*ebx]   ; eax = [eax]*[esi+4*ebx]
         mov    esi, edx           ; use esi instead of edi: esi = edx

         cdq              ; convert 32bit eax to 64bit eax:edx needed for division.

         idiv   [esi+3]   ; the remainder is in edx
         mov    edi, edx  ; store it in edi in order to use edx later.

         mov    eax, ecx  ; we can divide only eax:edx

         cdq

         idiv   [esi+3]   ; the second remainder is in edx

         or     edi, edx

         mov    eax, 0          ; prepare for the output value
         cmp    edi, [ebx+20]
         jg     end             ; edi is greater than [ebx+20]
         inc    eax             ; edi is less or equal than [ebx+20] so make eax = 1
end:
         retn
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me, and your answer was very concise, thank you very much!